# Error in time library in python and can't install time

Tags: python, time, pip

I have this code

```
class Timer():
def __init__(self, synch=None):
    self.synch = synch or (lambda: None)
    self.synch()
    self.times = [time.time()]
    self.total_time = 0.0

def __call__(self, include_in_total=True):
    self.synch()
    self.times.append(time.time())
    delta_t = self.times[-1] - self.times[-2]
    if include_in_total:
        self.total_time += delta_t
    return delta_t
```

and I get the error

> self.times = [time.time()]
> NameError: name 'time' is not defined

I have imported time but haven't installed it cause I was told it's built in.
When I try to install it I get the error

> no such option: --build-dir

when I downgrade pip to 20.2.4 it tells me that I cant install time without the newest version of pip.
What should I do?

Comment: so what are your imports at the top of the script? There should be `import time` ... And yes, you don't install the time module, it comes with the standard library of your Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment but I don't have enough reputation.  However, the `time` module is built in.  I don't understand why you are trying to install `time` via pip.  Try making a very simple python file that simply returns the result of `time.time()`.  If that works, then something is wrong with your code.  If that doesn't work, then the time module is likely missing from your python installation.